# AJAX Search System with spaces not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, search

Below is the code I am using.
If I search Hello+World, or Hello%20World then the search on the database is correct

However, if I use Hello World then I do not receive any results.  How can I mod this code to deal with spaces please?

Im not very good with JAVA so I really need some help!!

Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //show loading bar
    function showLoader1(){
        $('.search-background1').fadeIn(200);
    }
    //hide loading bar
    function hideLoader1(){
        $('.search-background1').fadeOut(200);
    }   
    $("#pagesn .pages li").click(function(){
        //show the loading bar
        showLoader1();      
        $("#pagesn .pages li").css({'background-color' : ''});
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#A5CDFA'});                
        $("#resn").load("funcs/func_search.php?page=" + this.className, hideLoader1);
    });

    // by default first time this will execute
    $(".1").css({'background-color' : '#A5CDFA'});
    showLoader1();
    $("#resn").load("funcs/func_search.php?page=1",hideLoader1);

    //For Search Results
    var qu=$("#a-j-search-term").val();


    $("#pages-search .pages li").click(function(){
        //show the loading bar
        showLoader1();      
        $("#pages-search .pages li").css({'background-color' : ''});
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#A5CDFA'});
        var qu=$("#a-j-search-term").val(); 

        $("#ress").load("funcs/func_search.php?page=" + this.className +"&q="+qu, hideLoader1);
    });

    $("#ress").load("funcs/func_search.php?page=1&q="+qu,hideLoader1);


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode the querystring to make it valid for URL's

```
var qu   = encodeURIComponent( $("#a-j-search-term").val() );
var page = encodeURIComponent( this.className );

$("#ress").load("funcs/func_search.php?page=" + page + "&q=" + qu, hideLoader1);
```

or let jQuery handle it

```
$("#ress").load("funcs/func_search.php", {
    page : this.className, 
    q    : qu
}, hideLoader1);
```

Comment: The amount of time I have been messing around trying to substitute ' ' for %20 and just crashing the code.  I knew it was simple but couldn't quite get there.  You are a gent!!!  Thank you very much for your help, all working now!